# Stackoverflow.com design is distorted when scaled

Tags: feature-request, design

I have problems with vision, so I prefer to view web sites on increased scale. On scales more than 110% question headers become partially visible. IMHO using "rubber" design, that tries to show all content independently on it's container size, is much more preferable.

**UPDATE**: Switching to "Full zoom" instead of "Text zoom" desides the problem, but then all linked to page raster images, like screenshots, become disgusting. I think, that adopting site to be looking good with text-only zoom would be great.

Comment: Relevant: [The two types of browser zoom](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-two-types-of-browser-zoom.html)

Comment: Which browser are you using? Are you actually zooming or just increasing the font size? See the blog post I linked above for the difference.

Comment: I'm using lastest Firefox with NoSquint extension. Text-only zoom, see updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it is trivial to switch over to the [mobile site](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/mobile-stack-exchange/).  Just click the link at the bottom for the mobile site.  The mobile site seems to scale to various font sizes without any problems.

<strike>One solution that might work for you would be to install something like [User agent switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/).  Then force your browser to appear as an iPhone for the stackexchange sites, stackexchange has some tweaks for [mobile](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/mobile-stack-exchange/) browsers.  My vision is also not great.  I frequently find that mobile optimized sites tend to scale a lot better to larger font sizes.</strike>

Of course I would really like there be a way that I could request the mobile optimized site without having to mess around with user agents, but that doesn't seem to be possible yet.

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of a page on a SE site. There is a link there labelled "mobile" that will enable the mobile version of the site. No user agent tricks necessary.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that link there before.  That works fine for me, thanks.

Comment: Thank you, mobile version is nice :)